# Motor wire current

Tags: current, brushless-dc-motor

The picture of my motor is below. How do I calculate how much current is in each of the 3 "black" motor wires going into the motor? It is a BLDC motor.

[image]

[image]

Comment: how many wires are there?

Comment: why do you want to do this?

Comment: There are 3 wires going into the motor my friend. You can see the 3 wires on the left hand side of the picture.

Comment: And when run at rated voltage and maximum continuous power is dissipated then maximum continuous current will be drawn (assuming the source can supply it).

Comment: Do you mean the internal copper wires?

Comment: @FawazAlLawz there are a lot of wires inside the motor ... you did ask `how much current is in each individual motor wire?`

Comment: @jsotola My friend, I meant current in each of the 3 "black" motor wires going into the motor. You can see the black wires in the left of the picture. Ty

Comment: @Andyaka I meant current in each of the 3 "black" motor wires going into the motor. You can see the black wires in the left of the picture. Ty

Comment: why calculate the current, when you can measure it instead?

Comment: @jsotola I want to calculate and measure it also to make sure the values are as expected on paper and in the field. Can I just use a oscilloscope in series with one of the black wires? If I do that, I will see a sine wave type of current...wont it? Thank you my friend.

Comment: an oscilloscope displays voltage variations ... you would have to insert a very low value resistor between the motor and the motor controller ... then measure the voltage across the resistor ... research `shunt resistor`

Answer (score 1):

For a typical "wye" or "star" wound motor, all of the line current must go through the  two of the phases.  Usually, while switching, one phase is tied to the line, one is grounded and the other is floating.  So, each phase has the full line current but only 2/3 of the time.  The average phase current is therefore 2/3 of the line current.  The peak instantaneous current in a phase is equal to the peak instantaneous line current.